# Spliting a PDF file in PHP, reading it, and returning a result

Tags: php, pdf, split

Here's how the system should work:

1. Admin uploads a multi-page PDF file, in which every page contains a
   unique code for every user.
2. The system should split the file into separate pages.
3. User logs in. The system gets his ID as a variable (the unique code which exists in PDF file).
4. The system shows every user only those pages which contain their ID.

I'm not asking for any code, just the name of some PDF libraries which can do the exact thing I'm looking for :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take a look at [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), especially  the paragraph labelled 4.

Answer (score 4):

You may try this function to split all of the pages from a larger PDF file into single-page PDF files.

#### Installation

```
composer require setasign/fpdf
composer require setasign/fpdi
```

#### Code

```php
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

/**
 * Split all of the pages from a larger PDF file into single-page PDF files.
 *
 * @param string $filename The filename of the PDF to split
 * @param string $directory The output directory for the new PDF files
 *
 * @return void
 */
function split_pdf(string $filename, string $directory)
{
    $pdf = new Fpdi();
    $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($filename);
    $file = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    // Split each page into a new PDF
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pageCount; $i++) {
        $newPdf = new Fpdi();
        $newPdf->addPage();
        $newPdf->setSourceFile($filename);
        $newPdf->useTemplate($newPdf->importPage($i));

        $newFilename = sprintf('%s/%s_%s.pdf', $directory, $file, $i);
        $newPdf->output($newFilename, 'F');
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```php
split_pdf('test.pdf', 'split/');
```

Comment: Unfortunately a part of this package is no longer maintained, an alternative?

`Package setasign/fpdi-fpdf is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.`

Comment: @Meloman This was just a meta-package. You can just install `setasign/fpdf` and `setasign/fpdi` directly.

Comment: Thanks @odan, I think it could be useful for others.